# My sinon stub is not showing up in my Angular service

Tags: jasmine, sinon

I am trying to test an Angular service.  I have a constant called `keys`.  I am trying to mock out this constant, but I continue to get the real constant.  Here is my test:

```
  describe('getSuperheroes()', function() {
    var mockKeys;
    beforeEach(function() {
      mockKeys = sinon.stub({apikey: 'test'});
      module(function($provide) {
        $provide.value('keys', mockKeys);
      });
    });
    it('should populate superheroes[] with result from get()', inject(function(superheroService, $httpBackend) {
      expect(superheroService.superheroes).toBeNull();
      $httpBackend.when('GET', 'http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?apikey=test').respond({
        data: {
          results: 100
        }
      });
      superheroService.getSuperheroes();
      $httpBackend.flush();
      expect(superheroService.superheroes).toBe(100);
    }));
```

Here is my `keys` module:

```
angular.module('marvelApp').constant('keys', {
  apikey: 'vip number'
});
```

And here is my service:

```
angular.module('marvelApp').factory('superheroService', function($resource, $q, keys) {
  return {
    superheroes: null,
    getSuperheroes: function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var that = this;
      if(this.superheroes) {
        deferred.resolve(that.superheroes);
      } else {
        this.getResource().get({
          apikey: keys.apikey
        }, function(data) {
          that.superheroes = data.data.results;
          deferred.resolve(data.data.results);
        });
      }
      return deferred.promise;
    },
    ...
  };
});
```

What am I doing wrong in my test that isn't allowing me to mock out the `keys` module.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the wrong method that `$provide` offered me.  I was trying `$provide.value()` when the proper function should of been `$provide.constant()` because I was trying to mock a constant.  Easy peasy.

Comment: Please remember to select your own answer :)